# how to get results of function with datatype nvarchar

Tags: sql, function, sql-server-2012

I have a database table like this

```
  Id   Code   Amount   Formula
  -------------------------------------
   1    A01   20.00   
   2    A08   0.00    dbo.ufn_Test(40)  
   3    A03   0.00    dbo.ufn_Test(60)
```

My `Formula` column is a string with name as a function in my database, how can I return the result into the `Amount` column?

My table has about 100000 rows so when I used `while()` it takes a lot of time.
I'm using SQL Server 2012

I've used dynamic SQL like this:

```
DECLARE @_j INT = 1

WHILE (@_j<=(SELECT MAX(Id) FROM #Ct_Lv))
BEGIN
    SET @_CtLv = (SELECT Formula FROM #Ct_Lv WHERE Id = @_j)

    DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX)
    DECLARE @result NUMERIC(18, 2) = 0

    SET @sql = N'set @result = N''''SELECT''' + @_CtLv

    EXEC sp_executesql @sql, N'@result float output', @result out

    UPDATE #Ct_Lv
    SET Amount = @result
    WHERE Id = @_j

    SET @_j = @_j + 1
END
```

but my max @_j = 100000, I've run my code for 3 hours and it's still running

Comment: You have to use dynamic SQL to do what you want.  A `while` loop seems reasonable.  If there are lots of duplicate formulas, you can make it more efficient by only generating the values once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

one thing, i would like know here is, does id attribute is identity column ?

2nd most important part is, you are declaring variables @sql and @result for each row and you are taking max at every row iterate, which might decrease the performance. I am not sure, how much faster the solution i have been given here, but you can try it once.

```
Set Nocount On;

Declare  @_count        Int
        ,@_j            Int
        ,@_cnt          Int
        ,@_dynamicSql   Varchar(Max)
        ,@_formula      Varchar(Max)
        ,@_row25Cnt     Int

Select   @_count    = Count(1)
        ,@_j = 0
        ,@_cnt = 0
        ,@_dynamicSql = ''
        ,@_formula = ''
        ,@_row25Cnt = 1
From    #Ct_Lv As ct With (Nolock)

While (@_cnt < @_count)
Begin
    Select  Top 1
             @_j = ct.Id
            ,@_formula = ct.Formula
    From    #Ct_Lv As ct With (Nolock)
    Where   ct.Id > @_j
    Order By ct.Id Asc

    Select  @_dynamicSql = 'Update ct Set ct.Amount = f.result From #Ct_Lv As ct Join ( Select ' + Cast(@_j As Varchar(20)) + ' As Id, [fuctionResultAttribute] As result From ' + @_formula + ' ) As f On ct.Id = f.Id; '

    If (@_row25Cnt = 25)
    Begin
        Exec (@_dynamicSql)

        Select   @_dynamicSql = ''
                ,@_row25Cnt = 0
    End
    Else If ((@_cnt + 1) = @_count)
    Begin
        Exec (@_dynamicSql)

        Select   @_dynamicSql = ''
                ,@_row25Cnt = 0
    End

    Select   @_cnt = @_cnt + 1
            ,@_row25Cnt = @_row25Cnt + 1
End
```

Here, what i have done so far is, I am looping Id by Id and generating dynamic sql for each 25 rows, once count is reach to 25, that dynamic sql will be executed which will update your amount. and again start generating dynamic sql for next 25 rows, and when count is about to end and there would be no 25 rows as end then dynamic sql will be executed when loop about to end in 'else if' condition.

above my solution will work only in that case when there would be only one formula in formula column for each row.

Comment: thanks for answer. But i realize my problem is worse
In some case, i must have  the result in row 1000 before i run the function in row 1.
i'm trying to use CLR SQL 
any way thank you alot

Comment: I am sharing my thoughts here (don't mind please) why don't you make child table (with formula flags which denotes addition,subtraction etc) in which you will save actual values, where Id will be a foreign key, so its easy to taking result by join with your master/parent table as well.

Answer (score 0):

I just suggest one thing if `Formula` field calling the same function each time then better to store only parameter that you want to pass to the function, then you can easily process over huge data.

Else looping over huge data is not preferable way to perform any operation. So it's advisable to use some other trick over there in table structure and storing data.